# WebStorm: vue file cannot auto indent

Tags: web, ide, vuejs2, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2017.2, but when I edit `*.vue` file, I found that in the `<template> </template>` part, the editor can not auto indent when the `lang` property is set.

[image: pic1]

When unset the `lang` property, it works fine:

[image: pic2]

and in other file, the auto indent work fine, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently code style is applied only to the template and style attributes with the default language (without `lang` attribute). Please follow [WEB-25863](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25863) for updates